# Any way to use jQuery mobile widgets independently?

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site built using Twitter Bootstrap, but I'd like to incorporate jQuery Mobile's accordion widgets for collapsible content.  I've used their [download builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) and selected only the accordion widget.  I think the problem is there is still some code in the core jquery.mobile.js file that conflicts with bootstrap.js, because it ends up changing my links' behavior in the nav menu.  It treats every regular link as an ajax request, which really screws with my app.

Does anyone have experience with jQuery mobile and Bootstrap?  Is there a way to change default settings so that only the accordion widget is manipulated?  Or is there a better mobile-friendly alternative to that widget?  I sincerely appreciate just about any help I can get on this!

Comment: can you create a jsfidlle or a test page of wat you are working with . I will try to lend some help .

Comment: Sorry, I should have added my solution a while ago.  Disabling ajax for links makes the application run normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have updated this a while ago.  To disable ajax, run:

```
$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
```

This will cause all the links to be treated as normal anchors, making it compatible with Bootstrap.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ajaxLinksEnabled' of undefined`. I'm trying to set this after jQuery Mobile has been loaded. Doing a search for "ajaxLinksEnabled," it doesn't appear anywhere in the version of jQuery Mobile I'm using (v1.4.2).

Comment: Also, I have tried `$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.extend(  $.mobile , {
        linkBindingEnabled: false,
        ajaxEnabled: false
    });
});`, but that isn't working either. jQuery Mobile is still mangling any links on the page, *and* if I change the hash to, e.g., /the/page#some-hash, it will automatically redirect the page to /the/page/some-hash.

Comment: You're registering the event with jquery, but it will be called by jqm on init.  So the code should be put between the jquery include and the jqm include.  The way you're doing it, by the time you register the event, it's already been dispatched.

Comment: I should have specified explicitly in my second comment, but I'm registering that event listener after jQuery but before JQM. What I said in my first comment about "after jQuery Mobile has been loaded" was only regarding the direct setting of `$.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled` to false.

Comment: How does your code differ from this?

http://jsfiddle.net/senormoll/v67re1g7/1/

It seems to work fine with 1.4.2 for me.